# Win 10 - Can't open Desktop Apps from SearchBar

Tags: windows-10, search

I search with the keyword is "paint" in Search Windows. It returns me a list as in the picture. I can't Right click, Left click or Enter on Paint, nothing happen. Other Desktop Apps are similar. But I can open Paint 3D. 
Hope everybody help please.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gByfM.png)

Comment: Microsoft Community on this problem: [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/windows-10-cant-open-apps-from-search-bar/c0bc8b3a-e474-443a-b27c-6234b1061360). Try the "Most Helpful Reply".

Answer (score 0):

Repair your installation.
That's 1703 , and even explorer is a modern app.
If the Shell/StartUI is damaged, repairing the image itself is your only resolution. You cannot reinstall non-provisioned applications without upgrading or repairing.
I know it sucks to hear, but unless the problem is being caused by a third-party program (Have you tried a clean boot yet?) , there's no other way.
If you try a clean boot and it works again, try adding programs back into your startup one by one until you see the break recur. Start with AV or DLP software.

Answer (score 0):

You must allow apps to run in the background.

see this thread and go to AnswerWells reply: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/windows-10-creators-update-search-not-finding-apps/eaf70556-2344-474d-b633-e00140b0466d

This worked for me. I had blocked background apps and that actually prevents you from opening apps in search menu. However, a few apps (Trusted Windows App) can be opened anyways.

So if you changed privacy settings to not let apps run in background (like me) and then suddenly cannot start apps in menu, then this is for you.